# SP2010: Get all library names within a site using javascript client object model?

Tags: document-library, javascript, client-object-model, jquery

How do I get the names of all libraries within a given site using jquery/javascript?

the only way i know of is using getByTitle('listtitle'), but I would like all names of libraries (hopefully there is a way to do libraries only and not just all lists) in a site?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can query for only libraries tbh, an option is too look at the [SP.BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550040%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Something like this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
function Initialize()
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    this.lists = web.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(lists);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var count = this.lists.get_count();

    for (x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        if(this.lists.itemAt(x).get_baseType() === 1) {
            var listTitle = this.lists.itemAt(x).get_title();
            console.log(listTitle);
        }
    }              
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: thanks Anders.....i think baseType === '101' will get me libraries! thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 3):

The [SiteData web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774864%28v=office.12%29.aspx) will return all that data for you. The link is for SP 2007, but it still exists in 2010 and functions the same.

```
http://<Site>/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx
```

I'm not entirely sure where that would fit in within the client object model, but it would be easily accessed with a more familiar tool to me, [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com).